# High and current scores are not shown in Hat Dash if I start the game by pressing the up arrow

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

The Hat Dash game shows the current score and high score (in a session) if I press the Spacebar and start playing.

[image]

The game also gets started if I press the up arrow, but this time the current and high scores aren't shown and it also displays *Press Space to Start*.

[image]

The scores get shown and the Press Space to Start message disappears if I press the Spacebar while playing or after I lose. Can this be corrected?

Comment: There's a game?!?!?!?!

Comment: Yep, you can log in, play and top the Leader Board :) https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I see the leaderboard and WB dashboard, I just have no idea how to start the game.

Comment: Yeah, I've logged in, I see what hats I've earned, but don't see any Hat Dash link or box.  I guess it's something to do with the "konami" I saw in the source code, but I can't see how to activate the game.

Comment: No repro on Firefox/Ubuntu...

Comment: @wimi It is probably fixed now. Earlier it didn't work, but now it's working properly.